# the calculate days function is returning wrong count

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a javascript function and when i select dates like Nov 20 to Nov 22, i get a count of 2 instead of 3, what i am doing wrong here, i tried debugging the code but could not figure out what is going wrong

is it because of the timezone

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk3kJ.png)

Here is my JS Code

```
function dConvert(d, seprater = '/') {
    let aFormate = dateFormat.split(seprater);
    let aD = d.split(seprater);
    let oD = aFormate.reduce((acc, val, ind) => {
        acc[val] = aD[ind];
        return acc;
    }, {});
    return oD['yy'] + '-' + oD['mm'] + '-' + oD['dd'];
}

Date.prototype.addDay = function(days) {
    var date = new Date(this.valueOf())
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + days);
    return date;
}


function calcBusinessDays(startDate, endDate) {
    var count = 0;
    var curDate = startDate;
    if (startDate == endDate) return 1;
    let aTemp1 = startDate.split('/');
    let aTemp2 = endDate.split('/');
    let dDate1 = new Date(dConvert(startDate));
    let dDate2 = new Date(dConvert(endDate));
    let aWD = $('[name="WorkingDays"]').val().split(',');
    while (dDate1 <= dDate2) {
        var dayOfWeek = (dDate1.getDay() + 1).toString();
        var isWworkingDay = aWD.includes(dayOfWeek);
        let oD = {
            'm': dDate1.getMonth() + 1,
            'd': dDate1.getDate(),
            'y': dDate1.getFullYear(),
        };
        let tempDate = (oD.m < 9 ? "0" + oD.m : oD.m) + '/' + (oD.d < 9 ? "0" + oD.d : oD.d) + '/' + oD.y;
        if (isWworkingDay && (aHolidayDate.indexOf(tempDate) == -1))
            count++;
        dDate1 = dDate1.addDay(1);
    }
    return count;
}
```

Please what is wrong here

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're wanting to include the first date in the calculation of your date range. If you're wanting to do that you should have `count = 1` instead of `count = 0`. If you don't your while loop will be one short.